# Microsoft Graph API Get Events started to return 401 UnAuthorized

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I have an App which uses Microsoft Outlook rest api to get the calendar events.

Followed instructions as per :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/version-2.0/use-outlook-rest-api

**The App was working fine, but all of a sudden since a couple of days back i am getting UnAuthorized error (401) for Get Events API**

Looking into the response headers this is the exception
"2000003;reason="The audience claim value is invalid 'https://graph.microsoft.com'.";error_category="invalid_resource"

Below is my code

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
   { "client_id", "clientId" },
   { "scope", "https://graph.microsoft.com/Calendars.ReadWrite People.Read offline_access" },
   { "code", code },
   { "state", "12345" },
   { "redirect_uri", "http://localhost:3000/home" },
   { "grant_type", "authorization_code" },
   { "client_secret", "secret key" }
};

            var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);

            var response = await client.PostAsync("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token", content);
            string token = string.Empty;
            if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var tokenResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TokenResponse>(responseString);
                token = tokenResponse.access_token;
            }
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);

            Events events = new Events();
            var responseEvents = await client.GetAsync("https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/events");
            if (responseEvents.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                var responseString = await responseEvents.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                events = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Events>(responseString);
                ViewBag.Message = token;
            }
            else
            {
                var responseString = await responseEvents.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }
```

Comment: Have you tried calling the [Graph API `/events` endpoint](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_list_events) (which is the sope you're requesting) instead of the Outlook API endpoint?

Comment: you mean https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events, i tried this end point as well, it says Bad Request

Comment: Hmmm.. Are you able to access the events using Graph Explorer? Also, including an example of the token you're getting back might prove helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to fix this by changing the scope from 
https://graph.microsoft.com/Calendars.ReadWrite to https://outlook.office.com/Calendars.ReadWrite.

With this change in my above code its started working fine now.

Not sure in the first place why it worked earlier with scope https://graph.microsoft.com/Calendars.ReadWrite